# button visibility on VideoView after using videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true); Android

Tags: android, android-videoview, z-order

I have to use    videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true) compulsorily on android. But after using this I cannot display a button on videoView. Is there any way to display a button on videoView even after setting videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true)?